# Prism: How to inject a view-model instance in a region?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, viewmodel, prism

After weeks of using Prism I have been through every kind of navigation methods. But there is still one thing that I haven't been able to achieve with Prism "out-of-the-box": navigate to a view-model instance. It is really easy to navigate to a view-model or view **type** but there is actually no way to navigate to a real view-model **instance**.

For example when I have a list of different view-model instances (different type too), if one is selected and I want to display it in my content region, I cannot achieve it unless I publish the change through event aggregation and I do not want that because this gets me stuck to one kind of view in my content region. What I want to do is to register a view-model instance into a region, so the view can load dynamically from data templates.

Actually I achieved to do this by creating a RegisterViewModelWithRegion as an extension method to RegionManager, it works well but it is not really neat as I have to manually lookup through my application resources, load the view, attach my view-model instance and then add the view to my region.

I really feel that I am missing something into the architecture because this kind of practice seem obvious to me but apparently I cannot find anybody having the same concern.

Your help and experience would much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some discussions with the Prism team, I found out that actually, using the `Region.Add(object view)` method to inject a view-model in a region is totally ok. It will give exactly the same result (except for some minor case).

I inspected the *ItemsControlRegionAdapter* and all it does in the end is

```
regionTarget.ItemsSource = region.Views;
```

`regionTarget` being the target control (*ListBox* for example) and `region.Views` property being the objects you inject into your regions.

Of course, thanks for your help Rachel :-)

Comment: I am looking for the same thing but how the ViewModel instruct the Region to show specific View if injected through `Region.Add(viewModelInstance)`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/) I wrote on using Navigation with MVVM

You need a `ViewModel` for your application shell that defines which `ViewModel` is the `CurrentPage`. To change ViewModels, you just fire an Event which the shell will pick up to set the `CurrentPage` to whatever ViewModel should be current.

You can switch pages with something like this with PRISM:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangePageEvent>()
    .Publish(new ChangePageEventArgs(this));
```

I'm sure there's other ways to accomplish this, but so far I find this way the simplest

Comment: Actually, at my company, before moving to Prism we had our own MVVM framework and the Shell view-model was also controling workspaces navigation. Now that we use Prism, as it already provides this concept of workspaces navigation (RegionManager) we are trying to completely integrate Prism functionalities, thus getting rid of manual workspace management.

Comment: @UCodia PRISM's `RegionManager` is a nice concept, but I don't use it often because I don't like some of the limitations associated with it. I would recommend not using it as your sole method of navigation.